# jquery datepicker for ajax content fails after first load

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, modal-dialog

I have a script that generates a modal dialog and inside of that, I would like to put a jquery ui datepicker. I'm currently using the following code:

```
$('#datepicker').live('click', function() {
  $(this).datepicker({showOn:'both'}).focus();
});
```

Which works just fine the first time I open the dialog and click on the input box assigned the 'datepicker' id.

The problem is that after I close that dialog (which removes its markup from the DOM) and re-open it, the datepicker no longer works.

I have tried calling $('#datepicker').die() upon closing the dialog and then re-binding to the #datepicker input upon re-opening it, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm really stumped on this one. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: using simple identifiers like "datepicker" when you're loading dynamic content into dialogs can cause problems. If you have 2 dialogs, for example, and both have a datepicker, then you wind up with two things in the page with "id" of "datepicker" - and that's bad.  I speak from experience here :-)  Other than that it's hard to tell without maybe seeing an example with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the removal of the triggering element from the DOM is your issue.  Why not just [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) your modal window and then [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) it when you need to?  I believe that would take care of your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really an option, since the content that triggers the modal window also changes and the contents of the modal dialog vary based on the parent content+xml from the back end. It's just way easier to re-generate the dialog each time we need it. I know it sounds convoluted, and it sort of us, but there are some pretty strict confines I have to work within that are, sadly, beyond my control.

You have given me an idea, though. I will try replacing the #datepicker input on the fly with one that already exists (hidden) within the DOM and see if that does the trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me today.
I had the same problem. I was reinitializing the same element by it's id in a dialog. The first time, I brought the dialog up it worked. Thereafter it would not. So, just giving the element a class of `datepicker` executing `$(".datepicker").datepicker()` after, each time I reopened the dialog fixed the problem.

Remember to put this class in the style sheet i.e.:

```
.datepicker {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, using a class instead of an ID (i.e. '.datepicker' instead of '#datepicker') fixed the issue, even though there was only ever one occurance of #datepicker on the DOM.

Even then, it only works if there's another hidden input with the .datepicker class attached.

So it was sort of a combination of both suggestions that fixed it.

Thanks to both of you for the help!

Comment: this does not seem to work for me since the javascript does not run after the inserted tags have been put in place.